# Append a list item through loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

How do I append a new list item through loop in JQuery. Every time the user clicks the button, a new item gets appended showing the correct index.

Here a sample of my code:

```
$('#append').click(function() {
    $('ul#myList > li').each(function(i) {
        var content = "<li>" + "Item" + (1+i) + "</li>";
        $(this).append(content);
    });
});
```

Output should be like

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the total length and assign that value to the variable then use this code

```js
 $('#append').click(function() {
          var contentLength = $('ul#myList > li').length;
          var content = "<li>" + "Item" + (contentLength+1) + "</li>";
          $('ul#myList').append(content);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="append">Add More</button>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item1</li>
</ul>
```

Below is the code for prepend

```js
 $('#prepend').click(function() {
          var contentLength = $('ul#myList > li').length;
          var content = "<li>" + "Item" + (contentLength+1) + "</li>";
          $('ul#myList').prepend(content);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prepend">Add More</button>

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried but the output comes like this



   `Item 1
    Item5
    Item 2
    Item5
    Item 3
    Item5
    Item 4
    Item5`

Comment: 1 second why are you using each function when you want to add li on click only

Comment: Should I not use each function?? Will it work without it??

Comment: check the code its working fine its adding li on button click

Comment: hey @gaurav how do i write the same thing for prepend...the output be like

`1 item prepended
2 item prepended
Item 1 
Item 2`

Comment: just use `.prepend()` function instead of `.append()` function.

Comment: that won't work...the output now is 

Item 6
Item 5
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#append').click(function() {
    $("#myList").append(" <li>Item " + ($('#myList > li').length + 1) + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: it works but i want only 1 element to be appended once...your code appends 4 at a time

Comment: It should append 1 element once..can you put your code here?:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#append').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('ul#myList').append(function() {
    return "<li>" + "Item " + ($('ul#myList > li').length + 1) + "</li>";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
<button id="append" type="button">Append</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<ul id="addlist">
<li>item 0</li>
</ul>
<div class="clickme">
Click me to add li
</div>

$('.clickme').click(function() {
var findlist=$('ul#addlist > li').length;
$('<li> item '+findlist+'</li>').appendTo('#addlist');

});
```